# Limit on supreme of function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. Let $a\in(0,\infty)$ then define $$M_a=\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)} |f(x)|.$$ How to prove strictly that $M_a\to 0$ as $a\to \infty$?

Comment: Back to definitions. What does "$f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$" actually _mean_ (in terms of definitions)? The proof falls out of that rather quickly.

Comment: @DanielFischer, it means the following: $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists K>0$ such for any $x>K$ implies that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: And that tells us what about $M_a$ for $a \geqslant K$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, We get that $M_K\leqslant \varepsilon$. But for any $a>K$ we have $M_a\leqslant \varepsilon$. Because $M_K=\sup \limits_{(K,\infty)}|f|=\max\{\sup \limits_{(K,a]}|f|, \sup \limits_{(a,\infty)}|f|\}\leqslant \varepsilon$. Hence $M_a=\sup \limits_{(a,\infty)}|f|\leqslant \varepsilon$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. And hence $M_a \to 0$ as $a \to \infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Dear Daniel! Thanks a lot for your ongoing assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $a > 0$ such that $x \geq a$ only if $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$, *i.e.* such that $\sup_{x \geq a}|f(x)| \leq \varepsilon$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes. I wrote answer above. You can take a look at this.

Comment: Such things happened all the time; I think maybe we do need timestamp :)